# Javascript- Twitter bot not working on Heroku, but works locally

Tags: javascript, heroku, twitter, bots

I am trying to create a Twitter but that posts on certain days. It works fine locally, but on Heroku, it doesn't work.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!

if(dd<10) {
  dd = '0'+dd
}

if(mm<10) {
  mm = '0'+mm
}

today = mm + '/' + dd;


if(today=="07/06"){
  var name="John Doe";
  tweetIt();
}




function tweetIt(){
 var tweet= {status: "Happy Birthday "+name+"! (One Week Early)"}

  T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

  function tweeted(err,data, response){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log("Success!")
    }
  }
  }
```

Another code that I wrote which posts random numbers every 30 seconds works fine, so I believe the server itself is fine, just the code.

Comment: What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: The code runs fine on local, but does not work on heroku. It says it's been initialized, but nothing after

Comment: nvm fixed it by setting the code on an interval